# bodyParser(urlencodedParser) Data is Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to apply a very basic POST request which succeeds but the data is `undefined` on the server side.

```
function SubmitFunction()
{
  var text = '{"name":'+'"'+document.getElementById("text1").value+'"'+'}';
  var encoded = encodeURIComponent(text);
  var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  http.open("POST", "/users");
  http.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  http.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
      alert(http.responseText);
    }
  }
  http.send(encoded);
}
```

text format is :  `{"name":"Username"}`

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })

app.post('/users', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400)
  res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.name)
})
```

Comment: Please post your actual code rather than links to images of your code.

Comment: It looks like you're sending (hand-constructed) JSON but with a header suggesting form encoding. Which do you actually want to use?

Comment: well i read that in order to POST you need to serialize-encode the data ?or i got it wrong ? i also need to send the data in JSON format .. Thanks in advance and sorry for the images , it's my first post :)

Comment: Kindly check that you are sending the data in POST request.Use Postman chrome extension for it

Comment: Please fix your post as I asked originally.

Comment: As already mentioned, for [numerous reasons](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6680611) code is preferred over images.

Answer (score 0):

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();


app.post('/users', jsonParser, function(req, res){
    res.send('welcome, ' + req.body.name);
});
```

Please try the above code.I was able run the above code and get the necessary response. I used Postman client to test the above server side code.